# Drop Down Navigation - Two Tier Menu (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I have been working on ***figuring out how to make a double drop down menu***.

Live Page I am working with : http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/

The "**Entertainment**" button, will be the only one with a Drop Down.
I have set up the parent selection, but each one will have a small list of bands when hovered over.

*Example: "Dance" will have about 7 bands (Band #1 - Band#7)*
The secondary drop down should appear to the right of the parent drop down menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been struggling with this for some time.

**My Relavant HTML (nav) Markup :**

```
    <div id="main-nav">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="company"><a title="Company" href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/company.php"></a></li>
                <li id="entertainment"><a title="Entertainment" href="http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/entertainment.php"></a>
                    <ul id="sub">
                    <li id="dance"> <a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/guitarist-original-music.asp">Dance</a></li>
                    <li id="classicRock"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/guitarist-shows-covers.asp">Classic Rock | Top 40 | Rock</a></li>
                    <li id="country"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/commercial-tv-film-jingles.asp">Country</a></li>
                    <li id="rockabilly"><a href="http://www.jasontanzer.com/composer.asp">Rockabilly | Reggae | Bluegrass | Other</a></li> 
. . . . .  and so on.
```

**My CSS (nav) Markup :**

```
#nav #company a  {
    background:url(../images/navigation/nav-company.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:103px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 20px;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #company:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #company a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_company #company a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}

#nav #entertainment a  {
    background:url(../images/navigation/nav-entertainment.png) no-repeat;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:168px;
    margin:20px 27px 0 0;
    height:20px;}
    #nav #entertainment:hover > a {
    background-position:0 -20px;}
    #nav #entertainment a:active {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
    body#body_entertainment #entertainment a {
    background-position:0 -40px;}
. . . . . and so on.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your CSS already contains the [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) selector, I am assuming you don't care for browsers that don't support it (like IE6).

It [**can be done**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5xLm/) with just CSS. I added the text to the `<a>` elements for display purposes and added *Band #1 - Band#7* to *Dance* and a *Band #1* to the next item just to show the alignment with the top of the music genre.

Hope this helps :-)