# How to make a double drop down menu

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu

Hi I Have a navigation bar that has a drop down menu. I would like the drop down menu to 
make another drop down menu but how would I do this? Here is my code.

```
<ul id="navbarr">

                                <li class="current-page">
                                    <a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i><br />Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="portfolio.html"><i class="icon-camera"></i><br />Cities</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon-comments"></i><br />Blog</a>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="services.html"><i class="icon-tasks"></i><br />Categories</a><ul>



                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-tasks"></i><br />Demographic</a></li>

                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-tasks"></i><br />Crimes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-tasks"></i><br />Schools</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-tasks"></i><br />Lifestyles</a></li>

                                </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <a href="about.html"><i class="icon-user"></i><br />About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="contact.html"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i><br />Contact</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740009/drop-down-navigation-two-tier-menu-css-html

Answer (score 1):

How about making another unordered list inside the list element?

Like this:

```
<li class="current-page">
    <ul>
       <li>
           <a href="index.html"><i class="icon-home"></i><br />Home</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: He already has that, I think that the question is about styling.

Comment: Yes @mdesdev I mainly just having trouble with getting it to style correctly.